# how to release video file after creation (c# Splicer)?

Tags: c#, splicer

i use Splicer lib to create video in c# programm.

end of code:

```
IRenderer renderer1 = new AviFileRenderer(timeline, "1.avi");
IAsyncResult result = renderer1.BeginRender(null, null);
renderer1.EndRender(result);
```

After this "1.avi" stay blocked by program.
renderer1 has no Dispose method. How to clear this object?

Comment: No updates for 3 years and links to the now-dead codeplex for documebtation. I'd use a different library, or fork it and read the code to find out how to end the output(/fix the bug you're running into) if I was desperate

Comment: IRenderer is derived from IDisposable